# Forward the Wan IP to another Wan IP without changing the source address

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, forwarding, wide-area-network

I have tried this case by using the NAT function in iptables but fail

example. 
PC A IP is 1.1.1.1 (Win7)
My Server IP is 2.2.2.2 (CentOS 6.2)
target Server B is 3.3.3.3 (Windows server 2003)

Flow: PC A WanIP --> My Server A --> Server B (WanIP)

My iptables rules:

```
1. iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 3.3.3.3:80
2. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

finally, i can access server B website by enter 2.2.2.2:80

but when i checked the access log at Server B
i found it's source address had been changed to src:2.2.2.2 dst:3.3.3.3

please help me to do how to get the real address is src:1.1.1.1 dst:3.3.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Just a little suggestion: maybe you can use proxy instead of iptables forwarding? You can add X-Forwarded-For header and your access logs will show correct IP adress.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, using proxy to instead iptables is no problem, do u have any example or link for the similar case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

That's rewriting the source address to be server A's (`2.2.2.2`).  You may find that removing it breaks any number of other things, but that's the line that's currently doing what you say you don't want done.

**Edit**: as I said, "*you may find that removing it breaks any number of other things*".  Especially if it turns out that either PC A's real address, server B's real address, or both, are RFC1918 addresses (ie, private addresses from the ranges 10/8, 172.16/12, and 192.168/16), then you will have to work out how to exempt this punchthrough from the NAT without breaking NAT for everything else, and sort out routing for the return-half traffic, which may well require root on server B.  Since you have chosen to redact all the IP addresses in your question, and we know nothing about the routing tables on either the PC or server B, nor any of your other current firewall rules, it's hard to tell how much of this will be necessary or problematic.

Comment: after removed this line, i cannot access this web link~ is there need to add some other rules?